# FieldError while using Q objects- cannot resolve keyword __ into field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Fairly new to django.
contructign view for index page . using 'complex lookups using `Q` objects' as in documentation.
Coming across the following error

> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/?q=wretched Django Version:     1.11.12
>   Exception Type:   FieldError Exception Value:
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'album_title_icontains' into field. Choices
>   are: album_favorite, album_logo, album_title, artist, genre, id, song,
>   user, user_id
>
> Exception Location:
>     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in
>   names_to_path, line 1352 Python Executable:   /usr/bin/python Python
>   Version:  2.7.15

the function view causing problem is `index()` (given below)

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login_form.html')
    else:
        albums= Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        songs=Song.objects.filter(album=albums)
        num= Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
        req= request.GET.get("q")
        if req:
            albums= albums.filter(
                Q(album_title_icontains=req) |
                Q(artist_icontains=req)
            ).distinct()
            songs=songs.filter(
                Q(song_title_icontains=req)
            ).distinct()
        context={
        'object_list': albums,
        'num': num,
        'songs': songs
        }
        return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)
```

the **models.py** file file is as given below

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse



class Album(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    artist= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album_logo= models.FileField()
    album_favorite= models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title+' by '+ self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    album= models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    audio_file= models.FileField(default='')
    is_favorite= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        alb= self.album
        return reverse('music:detail',kwargs={'pk':alb.pk})
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need dundee('__') double underscore to use the filters.

```
albums= albums.filter(
                Q(album_title__icontains=req) |
                Q(artist__icontains=req)
            ).distinct()
            songs=songs.filter(
                Q(song_title__icontains=req)
            ).distinct()
```

Comment: Silly me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is correct, just a minor typo. you just needed **Double-Underscore :-** 
   `__`
 for your lookups. **[From docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)**

**Correct - `Views.py`**

```
def index(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'music/login_form.html')
else:
    albums= Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    songs=Song.objects.filter(album=albums)
    num= Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
    req= request.GET.get("q")
    if req:
        albums= albums.filter(
            Q(album_title__icontains=req) |
            Q(artist__icontains=req)
        ).distinct()
        songs=songs.filter(
            Q(song_title__icontains=req)
        ).distinct()
    context={
    'object_list': albums,
    'num': num,
    'songs': songs
    }
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)
```